# The limit of a Poisson CDF as rate parameter and number of summands grow to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, asymptotics, power-series, probability-limit-theorems

To be more specific, we want to evaluate the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor c\cdot \log(n)\rfloor} e^{-\lambda_n} \frac{\lambda_n^k}{k!}$ where $\lambda_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}$.

A helpful fact, I think, is that $\frac{\lambda_n}{\log(n)}\to 1$ as n goes to infinity. Intuitively speaking, it makes sense that when $c\geq 1$ the limit is 1 since the summation will "include" the  largest summands. Whereas if $c < 1$ then the summands in the series will all approach $0$ since the number of summands is not "keeping up" with the growing rate parameter. Therefore the limit of the CDF in this case is $0$. I am basing my intuition in the idea that the largest summands are those where $k$ is very close to $\lambda_n$. I am unsure how to prove the result in a rigorous way. A probabilistic approach would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the point of the $\lfloor c \log(n)\rfloor$ -- couldn't you replace with $s_n$ where $s_n$ are the values of $n$ where $\lfloor c \log(n)\rfloor - \lfloor c \log(n+1)\rfloor > 0$? Then you can do limits on this subsequence?

Comment: $c log(n) $ is a growing sequence. With the floor function, it represents  the number of summands. When n changes by 1 unit, it is possible that this number doesn’t change. If there is another formulation of the same problem I am happy to learn more

Comment: I get that, but why is it important for this problem -- why do you want the $\lambda_k$ values to grow a lot faster than the sample space? Basically, why not just use $n$ as the upper summation limit?

Comment: The Poisson Rv takes values from 0 to infinity. I think the rate at which you include the summands in relation to the growing rate parameter affects the value of the CDF.

Comment: You might want to use the "helpful fact" by introducing the ratio as :  $\lambda_n \mapsto \frac{\lambda_n}{\log n} \times \log n$ . After doing this, it might further help to make the substitution $\log n \mapsto m$ where as $n \to \infty$, $m \to \infty$

Comment: Interesting. I am not sure how to get the result from the transformations.